# Is this c++ code containing reinterpret_cast between templated types well-defined?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, reinterpret-cast

https://onlinegdb.com/RU3bYEfCB

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//--------------------Foo------------------
template<int Index>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(string first, string second, string third) {
    foo_[0] = first;
    foo_[1] = second;
    foo_[2] = third;
  }

  string operator()() const {
    return foo_[Index];
  }

 private:
  string foo_[3];
};

//---------------------Bar------------------
class BarBase {
 public:
  virtual string operator()() const { return "BarBase"; };
};

template<int Index>
class Bar : public BarBase {
 public:
  Bar(string first, string second, string third) {
    bar_[0] = first;
    bar_[1] = second;
    bar_[2] = third;
  }

  string operator()() const {
    return bar_[Index];
  }

 private:
  string bar_[3];
};

//---------------------Wrapper------------------
class WrapperBase {
 public:
  virtual string operator()() const { return "WrapperBase"; };
};

template<typename T>
class Wrapper : public WrapperBase {
 public:
  Wrapper(T* functor) : functor_(functor) {}
  
  string operator()() const {
    return (*functor_)();
  }
 
 private:
  T* functor_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<0> foo0("A", "B", "C");
    Foo<1>& foo1 = *reinterpret_cast<Foo<1>*>(&foo0);
    Foo<2>& foo2 = *reinterpret_cast<Foo<2>*>(&foo0);
    cout<< "foo: " << foo1() << foo2() <<"\n";
    
    Bar<0> bar0("A", "B", "C");
    Bar<1>& bar1 = *reinterpret_cast<Bar<1>*>(&bar0);
    Bar<2>& bar2 = *reinterpret_cast<Bar<2>*>(&bar0);
    cout<< "bar: " << bar1() << bar2() <<"\n";
    
    WrapperBase* wrappedfoo0 = new Wrapper<Foo<0>>(&foo0);
    WrapperBase* wrappedfoo1 = new Wrapper<Foo<1>>(&foo1);
    WrapperBase* wrappedfoo2 = new Wrapper<Foo<2>>(&foo2);
    cout<< "wrapped foo: " << (*wrappedfoo1)() << (*wrappedfoo2)() <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo: BC
bar: AA
wrapped foo: BC
```

Foo and Bar are exactly equivalent with the only difference being that Bar inherits from a base class and the implemented operator is virtual, so Bar has a virtual function pointer while Foo does not.

I think I understand why bar prints `AA` while foo prints `BC` (please correct me if I'm wrong).
both classes are instantiated 3 times and there are three implementations of each operator(), with the respective index hardcoded. However, since Bar has a virtual function pointer, after the `reinterpret_cast`ing from Bar<0> to Bar<1> the virtual function pointer still points to the implementation of Bar<0>

What I wonder is whether this code is well defined, especially in the "Foo" and "Wrapped Foo" case. So that as long as I don't have inheritance in my functor, I can reinterpret_cast it to another Foo and when calling the operator() it will call it with the index of the template type of the current variable (respectively of the template type the wrapper was instantiated with)?

**//Edit:**
how does it look like if the Foo constructor is removed (and the foo_ member instead made public and initialized from the outside)?

Then it should constitute a POD and the standard  (9.2.18) says about reinterpret_cast and POD:

> A pointer to a POD-struct object, suitably converted using a
> reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
> bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [
> Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a POD-struct
> object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate
> alignment.

so, if the Foo constructor is removed, is the behaviour for Foo (and wrapped foo) therefore well-defined?

Comment: Most usages of `reinterpret_cast` leads to UB, including this one.

Comment: `Foo<T>` is a completely differnt type than `Foo<U>`.  This question basically boils down to is it safe to reinterpret a `long long*` into a `double*`, which is no, it's UB.

Comment: Note: `F<0>`, `F<1>`, `F<2>` are unrelated classes.

Answer (score 5):

All possible instantiations of `Foo` are *unrelated* to each other and are also unreleated to all possible instantiations of `Bar`, which again are also unrelated to each other.

The behaviour of using `reintepret_cast` between unrelated types is *undefined*.

It doesn't matter that the classes *look* the same. For example, consider

```
struct A{}; struct B{};
```

with

```
A a;
```

The behaviour of `reinterpret_cast<B&>(a)` is undefined too.

Comment: @Caleth: Was what I meant, honest ;-)

Comment: Thanks, how does it look like though if the Foo constructor is removed? in that case it should constitute to the definition of POD types, and since all POD types have the same data layout, the behaviour should be well-defined, shouldn't it?